# has_and_belongs_to_many permission filtering

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I need to find records between two models.

```
class Report
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

class Group
  has_and_belongs_to_many :reports
end
```

and join_table - reports_groups

I have an array of group ids, that I have access, for example `[1, 2]`.
And I need to find reports that have groups I have access to, only them.

```
If report has groups list like: [1], [2], [1,2] it is OK.
If report has - [1,2,3] - skip it.
If - [3,4] - skip it to.
```

I need only reports with permitted me groups.

Comment: what do you mean `If report has - [1,2,3]`

Comment: it means that report has groups with ids [1,2,3]. like report.groups.pluck(:id)  will return [1,2,3]

Answer (score 0):

Double check the name of your join table.

```
Report.where(
  'NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM reports_groups WHERE report_id = reports.id AND group_id IN (?))',
  [1, 2],
)
```

Comment: it is does not work, it still return, it tried report with group1, and group2. User had permission only for group1, query still return me that report

Answer (score 0):

Why do not just use complex query with `arel_table` building

`accessible_group_ids = [1, 2, ..., n]`
`Report.joins(:groups).where(Group.arel_table[:id].in(accessible_group_ids)).distinct`

Comment: it returns all reports where is at least one group I permitted for, It desn work

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, you need all of them to match